# Windows DNS Server taking too long respond when pinging domain

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

I'm running into an issue where if I ping a domain it takes close to 10 seconds to respond and all DNS queries that are not coming from a windows box fail.

Example:

- ping abc.local - will take 10 seconds to respond on a windows machine but would fail on Mac or  Linux.
- ping - host.abc.local will respond right away on any OS.

**The issue that this is causing that all none windows machine (Mac or Linux) do not get a response when trying to resolve abc.local.**

Any suggestions on what I should be looking at?

Comment: Pinging my domain.local and a customers domain.local also produces the same results, <10s, doesn't sound like an actual issue. I don't understand the second part of the first sentence.

Comment: Once it responds get the IP of the responding DC.  If you then ping that DC by IP does it reply right away?  Is the responding DC in the same AD site as the machine pinging it?

Comment: What problem is this actually causing you?

Comment: The issue that this is causing that all none windows machine (Mac or Linux) does not get a response when trying to resolve abc.local.